# What is this XSLT code doing?

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT. I have a block code that I don't understand.

In the following block what does `'*','*[@class='vcard']'` and `'*[@class='fn']'` mean?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">   <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>   <xsl:template match="/">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      <xsl:text><![CDATA[function show_hcard(info) {
      win2 = window.open("about:blank", "HCARD", "width=300,height=200," +      "scrollbars=no menubar=no, status=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no");
      win2.document.write("<h1>HCARD</h1><hr/><p>"   + info + "</p>");  win2.document.close();
    }]]></xsl:text>
    </script>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@class='vcard']">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@class='fn']">
    <u>
      <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="onMouseDown">
          <xsl:text>show_hcard('</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
          <xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </a>
    </u>   </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` matches all elements, `*[@class='vcard']` pattern matches all elements with `class` attribute of `vcard` value. From that you can figure out what `*[@class='fn']` may mean ;-)

I'd also suggest that you start [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt).

Answer (score 2):

Your stylesheet has four template rules. In English these rules are:

(a) starting at the top (match="/"), first output a script element, then process the next level down (xsl:apply-templates) in the input.

(b) the default rule for elements (match="*") is to create a new element in the output with the same name and attributes as the original, and to construct its content by processing the next level down in the input.

(c) the rule for elements with the attribute class="vcard" is to do nothing with this element, other than to process the next level down in the input.

(d) the rule for elements with the attribute class="fn" is to output

```
<u><a onMouseDown="show_hcard('X')">X</a></u>
```

where X is the text content of the element being processed.

A more experienced XSLT user would have written the last rule as

```
<xsl:template match="*[@class='fn']">
    <u>
      <a onMouseDown="show_hcard('{.}')">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </a>
    </u>   
</xsl:template>
```